# `note` in MDX v2 not look like the `note` in MDX v1

Tags: mdx

in MDX v1 the note look like here:

> Note

now in MDX v2 it looks bad:

Note

(     = space)

the code in mdx file is:
`> Note`

how can I get the UI like MDX v1?

I tried to use `blockquote` but not help:

```
<>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Note</p>
  </blockquote>
</>
```